How to change arrow style in Microsoft Word?
In Word (Windows), I inserted an arrow using Insert tab then Shapes button then arrow icon, then drawing the line. But I want to change the head style of the arrow, say, from a  wide  triangle  to a - > or to a long triangle.
Also, I want to change the size of the triangle head Microsoft's own instructions say to right-click and choose Format AutoShape from the shortcut menu, but there is no such option in the menu. There is only Format Shape, but in the pane that it opens there is no election of the arrow type.
I recall once seeing a pane or dialog with selection of arrow type, Where is it?


Click on the shape, on the title bar, you will see Shape outline.
Open the Shape outline dropdown list, you will see Arrows
Open the Arrows.  If it is not one of those displayed, click on more arrows.
Under Line Style, Arrow Settings, you can choose from the of 6 begin/end types.


There are some  options for changing begin / end arrow style near the bottom  the Format Shape pane  (right-click on the arrow or line and at t he bottom of the context menu choose Format Shape)

There is an Arrows submenu under Shape outlin edrop-down: elect the arrow or line click Format tab. There in the  Shape Styles  section, click Shape outline drop-down; choose Arrows. submenu near the bottom.
